# Disable page reload in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page with an update panel.
Normally, if I use an update panel, there should be postbacks only but no complete page reloads.

In my case, when I click a button, it always makes an page reload. Although this button is in an update panel.

What I found out: When I put

```
Response.End();
```

in the Button_Click Method, there is no reload.

My code on the .aspx:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUserDefault" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPrintSelectedArticles" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>

        <cc1:MenuButton runat="server" ID="btnPrintSelectedArticles" OnClientClick="return ShowPrintStickersPopUp();" ButtonText="Print" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

Page Load:

```
btnPrintSelectedArticles.MenuButton_Click += btnPrintSelectedArticles_MenuButton_Click;
```

Method:

```
    void btnPrintSelectedArticles_MenuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disables reload
        Response.End();
    }
```

MenuButton is a user control

Any ideas how to disable the reload of the complete page?

Edit:
This is the ShowPrintStickersPopUp JS from the ClienClick. It simply checks a gridview if there are any checkboxes checked

```
function ShowPrintStickersPopUp() {
        var gridView = document.getElementById('<% =gvArticles.ClientID %>');

        //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
        var inputs = gridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var n = 0; n < inputs.length; ++n) {
            if (inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[n].checked) {
                // If at least 1 checkbox is checked, open popup
                window.open('PrintStickersPopUp.aspx', 'Print Stickers', 'width=700,height=550');
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What does your ShowPrintStickersPopUp method look like? By default, the having your button within the UpdatePanel as well as providing a PostBackTrigger should prevent a full page postback, so I think there might be something in your ShowPrintStickersPopUp method that is causing a postback.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the ShowPrintStickersPopUp JS!

Comment: Not sure about what I'm gonna say, but did you try returning a false instead of true in your ShowPrintStickersPopUp?

Comment: @snaplemouton: That disables the reload, but it also disables the server click event =(

Comment: How about OnClientClick="ShowPrintStickersPopUp(); return false;"? Edit : and don't forget to remove the 2 returns in your script b4 trying.

Comment: Nope, any "return false" in the ClientClick prevents the server click event from being fired.

Comment: Try adding Type="button" to your button. If that doesn't fix it, you'll have to wait for someone who knows better then me about that problem. The default value of button is submit. It should post but not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Your client method looks good. Did you remember to add a ScriptManager object on your page? A lot of issues relating to UpdatePanels are related to not having one added.

Comment: If he has Jscript it should already be in a <script>. So he shouldn't need a ScriptManager. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @snaplemouton The ScriptManager object contains additional event handlers/scripting/etc. for managing the objects in the AJAX Control Toolkit. It's possible that there could be one in a master template, but hard to tell here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Yeah, you're right @Dillie-O, there is already a scriptmanager in the master site.